# Should logs, metrics, and analytics all go to one data lake or be stored separately?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

**Background:**

I am setting up my first elastic stack, and while I will be starting simple, I want to make sure I'm starting with good architecture. I would eventually like to have a solution for the following: hosting metrics, server logs (expressjs APM), single page app monitoring (APM RUM js agent), Redis metrics, MongoDB metrics, and custom event analytics (ie: sale, customer cancelled, etc).

**Question:**

Should I store all of this on one Elasticsearch cluster and use search to filter out the different cases, OR do I create a separate instance for each and keep them clearly defined to their roles.

(I would prefer the single data lake)

Answer (score 1):

**For logging use case:**

- you can store all the logs on a file system share before ingesting them into any search solution , so that you can re-ingest if needed
- after storage , you can either ingest them into just one cluster with different indices , or to multiple clusters , its open choice , but it depends on the amount of data
- if the size and compute of each justify a separatre ES cluster then do it , othervise , use a single cluster , with a failover cluster

**For metrics:**

- you can directly ingest them into one cluster with different index patterns
- if size and compute requirements justfies , make separate clusters
- make a failover/backup cluster if needed

In both the cases , you will also need to store the cluster snapshots.

I personally recommend ELK for logging uses case , and Promethous for metrics.

**Reporting/Analytics:**

For some use cases like reporting/analytics on monthly and yearly basis , the log data will be huge , and you will need to ingest the data from the file share into hadoop to summerize it/ roll up based on some fields , and then , ingest the reduced data into ELK , this can reduce the size and compute requirements by 1000 factor.